# Octave - sawtooth function

Tags: octave

I would like to plot a sawtooth function in Octave. I know that I can use the command "sawtooth(t)" but I don't have the package so I created the following function.

```
function x = pieceWise2bis(t)
x = zeros (size (t));

ind1 = t >= 10 & t < 13;
x(ind1) = +20;

ind2=t >= 13 & t < 16;
x(ind2) = -20;

ind3=t >= 16 & t < 19;
x(ind3) = +20;

ind4=t >= 19 & t < 22;
x(ind4) = -20;
endfunction
```

When I plot this function I don't get the result I'm looking for because I want a real sawtooth function and not a periodic function with crenels like that.
COuld someone tell me how I could adapt my code ? 
Thank you

Comment: May I ask why you "don't have the package"? I installed signal and the function works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the usual way to load sawtooth, by installing signal which requires control....  is not working, in any case you are  way better off writing this yourself.  Here's one of many ways to do it:

```
clear; %% this line tells octave the remainder is more than just a func.
## usage: ST = sawtooth (time)
function ST = sawtooth (time)
  ST=rem(time,2*pi)/2/pi;
endfunction

time=linspace(0,20,101); % second line of main program (clear is 1st)
PriSawtooth=sawtooth(time);
plot(time,PriSawtooth,'linewidth',1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Clinton for you answer. Could you please explain (or indicate a source) what the function/command "rem(...)" do exactly ?

Comment: @S.Pri  rem stands for remainder when the first argument is divided by the second, for instance rem(5,4)=rem(9,4)=rem(13,4)=1.  For this reason the rem function is quite useful when dealing with periodic functions.  In this case it is perfect since it does exactly what you want.  I suggest you draw a few sketches to convince yourself.  BTW if you are satisfied with an answer you should mark as such, so that other people don't spend time working on a solved problem.  You are the only one who can accept an answer to a question you asked.

Comment: @S.Pri: you can always type `help rem` (or whatever function name) at the Octave command prompt to learn more about a function.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. How can I indicate that my question has been answered.

Comment: @S.Pri If you look by each answer there is a gray check mark, click on the one by the answer you think is most helpful, and it becomes green

Comment: @ClintonWinant signal installs just fine for me (except for lots of deprecation warnings, but the package otherwise compiles properly). What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou after a few pages of warnings for the deprecated code, I thought that the installation was failing. I see now that it was not. Do you think the end user needs to see all those warnings, could octave only give a message if there is an error?

Comment: I agree, it is misleading to the average (i.e. non-package-developer) user. There are ways to silence those warnings, of course, but presumably that's an antipattern rather than a solution. Not sure if this has been raised in the octave bug tracker before or not, but if not it would sure be worth mentioning.